# EXASOL: Convert table data generated from query to json data (For creating graphs)

Tags: sql, lua, exasolution

I am trying to convert data from sql query to json format where different data would be considered for categories, Data values, Series directly in a graph. In SQL server we have a function called FOR JSON AUTO ; is there something similar in Exasol to achieve data conversion to JSON

Comment: Exactly what do you want ? Can you tell me a sample ?

Comment: Hello CodeMan, As we can convert data into json hierarchy in SQL can we do it same in EXASOL server.

Answer (score 0):

There are no built-in functions available in Exasol. However, try to create a UDF that could convert sql into json format. This can be done within the Exasol server.